# Move image on scroll like parallax

Tags: jquery, html, css

Do you know how I can make a parallax with position absolute (CSS solution or JavaScript solution are fine) ?
I want the "images" to move when I scroll down and up and don't be destroyed.

```css
.container{
  position : relative;
  min-width : 100vw;
}
.content{
  width : 90%;
  margin : 50px 5%;
  background-color : #888;
}
.content>p{
  margin-bottom : 20px;
  padding : 5px 15px;
  position : relative;
  z-index : 3;
}
#container-of-img-position-absolute>span{
  background-color : #F00;
  padding : 15px 35px;
  z-index : 2;
}
#img-1{
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : 70px;
}
#img-2{
  position : absolute;
  right : 0;
  top : 150px;
}
#img-3{
  position : absolute;
  left : 20%;
  top : 20%;
}
#img-4{
  position : absolute;
  right : 20%;
  top : 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="container-of-img-position-absolute">
    <span id="img-1">Img 1</span>
    <span id="img-2">Img 2</span>
    <span id="img-3">Img 3</span>
    <span id="img-4">Img 4</span>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

My code look something like this but I added text instead of images.

Thanks in advance !

**UPDATE :** That's why I have width and height at 0 px.
But I don't want the image to be inside the first container maybe I can do that with JQuery
The fact is I want to make a kind of parallax with the images.
Thanks for helping me through :)

```css
.container{
  position : relative;
  min-width : 100vw;
}
.content{
  width : 90%;
  margin : 50px 5%;
  background-color : #888;
}
.content>p{
  margin-bottom : 20px;
  padding : 5px 15px;
  position : relative;
  z-index : 3;
}
#container-of-img-position-absolute>img{
  background-color : #F00;
  position : fixed;
  z-index : 2;
}
#img-1{
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : 70px;
}
#img-2{
  position : absolute;
  right : 0;
  top : 150px;
}
#img-3{
  position : absolute;
  left : 20%;
  top : 20%;
}
#img-4{
  position : absolute;
  right : 20%;
  top : 35%;
}
```

```html
<div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
    <p>Don't want to be in this area</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">

  <div id="container-of-img-position-absolute">
    <img src="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/v_collection_png/128x128/shadow/dog.png" id="img-1">
    <img src="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/v_collection_png/128x128/shadow/dog.png" id="img-2">
    <img src="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/v_collection_png/128x128/shadow/dog.png" id="img-3">
    <img src="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/v_collection_png/128x128/shadow/dog.png" id="img-4">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container{
  position : relative;
  min-width : 100vw;
}
.content{
  width : 90%;
  margin : 50px 5%;
  background-color : #888;
}
.content>p{
  margin-bottom : 20px;
  padding : 5px 15px;
  position : relative;
  z-index : 3;
}
#container-of-img-position-absolute{
 position: fixed;
 z-index:999;
 }
#container-of-img-position-absolute>span{
  background-color : #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="container-of-img-position-absolute">
    <span id="img-1">Img 1</span>
    <span id="img-2">Img 2</span>
    <span id="img-3">Img 3</span>
    <span id="img-4">Img 4</span>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
    <p>Nice content !</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is a working example with sticky div.You need to use `position:fixed` instead of absolute.

### Update

Alternatively you can use simple JS plugin to achieve the same.

https://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/#installation

Here is a link and example.

```
<script src="js/stickUp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 //initiating jQuery 
 jQuery(function($) { 
 $(document).ready( function() { 
 //enabling stickUp on the '.navbar-wrapper' class 
 $('.navbar-wrapper').stickUp(); 
 }); 
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks ! But it doesn't work :/ The container of my images have a width and height of 0px
in this example it does work because it is span and not images

Comment: Why you are giving height and width of container to 0px?

Comment: I have put an update in my answer. Please try that? @KévinHuang

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, how can I mark it as resolved please ?

Comment: You have to approve my asnwer by accepting it. Use this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers @KévinHuang